# Calculate Two Date Fields - PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have two date fields:

dateFrom
dateTo

I want the total number of days calculated on the fly when the dates are picked from the fields.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$dateFrom = new DateTime("");
$dateTo = new DateTime("");
$difference = $dateFrom->diff($dateTo);
echo $difference->days;
?>
```

I am getting a:

Total # of Days: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() in /_New Site/vacationWeek.php on line 468

Comment: You called it in a false way.There are good examples [here](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to make the days update as the user changes the values in the field. As PHP is a server side language, this would require them to submit the form, and then you use the values from $_POST with DateTime::diff and display the result. If you want the page to update dynamically as they change the dates you'll need to use JavaScript

Comment: @CharlesRojas: not true, emptry string or null will also work as current/now time.

Comment: @Begueradj: he pasted working code. He only doesn't have the right php version to call DateTime::diff() method, like the error shows.

Comment: @Glavić Thanks for correction, I'll be more careful and remove my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your php version ? On mine your code work well.
[DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php): (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

Comment: This should not be accepted answer, since creating DateTime object is not a problem! Problem is [DateTime::diff()](http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.diff.php) method which came in php version 5.3.

Comment: You linked to the wrong function and you specified wrong version, so basecally your answer is completly wrong. Fix it and I will remove the downvote.